# Key counter for pressed keys (typed letters) and deleted letters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello everyone (I'm Spanish, excuse me if I have grammar or vocabulary mistakes)! 
I'm studying JS and Jquery now. One of my many exercises is to put a text input and count the pressed/written/typed AND deleted keys in real-time. 
So counting the keys that I write is fine, the problem is that I don't really know how to subtract, how to detect that you're deleting letters and subtract them.

This is the code for counting the keys pressed. But the problem is deleting. 
Help me, please! :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='es'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      i = 0;
      $(document).ready(function(){

        $("input").keypress(function(){
          $("span").text(i += 1);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Type your text: <input type="textarea" width="500px" height="300px">
    <p>Keys: <span>0</span></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Syed's answer is enough for a simple approach, it has a few drawbacks :

- If you hold backspace, it will reduce the count by one, even if you deleted the whole content.
- You have to specify the whole list of keys you don't want to trigger the count (F1-F12, shift, ...), and it's a little long (however, the problem is also occurring in your version of the code).

The solution you are looking for is a simple text length getter when something changes.

```js
i = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("input").keyup(function(event){
    i = $(event.target).val().length;
    $("span").text(i);
  });
});
```

As we are getting the event on our `<input>`, we `$(event.target)` will directly give us access to the `<input>` tag, therefore allowing us to get the contents (`.val()`) and retrieving the length of the text entered in it.

The `i` variable is not necessary, but may be useful if you want to show somewhere (added x characters) or (deleted x characters).

https://jsfiddle.net/e84L5d6c/1/

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I understood it perfectly :) Have a nice day!

Comment: Also, I used your code, that's why I'm voting you. But I changed the method for keydown instead of keyup. keyup() makes this to happen: it counts one by one, but if you keep a key pressed, it won't count until stop pressing, same if I press to delete, it won't count until I'm done deleting. Don't know if I'm explaining well. ^^'

Answer (score 1):

instead of your option try this

```
function updateLength() {
  $("span").text(this.value.length);
}
$('input').on('input', updateLength)
```

and if you still want to use your method then go try this

```
$('input').keyup(function(e) {
  console.log(e.keyCode);
  if(e.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46) {
    console.log('u :', i);
    i -= 1
    if (i < 0) i = 0
    $("span").text(i);
  } else {
    i += 1
    $("span").text(i);
  }
});
```

but i think above code is much cleaner.

Comment: Alright! Very appreciated! Thank you :) Have a nice day

Comment: consider upvoting my answer if you like the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by key code, and reduce the count.

**Note:** backspace will not trigger on `keypress` so I used `keyup`.

```js
 i = 0;
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("input").keyup(function(event){
            switch (event.keyCode) {
                case 8: // Backspace
                case 46: // delete
                  $("span").text(i -= 1);
                case 9: // Tab
                case 13: // Enter
                case 37: // Left
                case 38: // Up
                case 39: // Right
                case 40: // Down
                   break;

                default:
                   $("span").text(i += 1);
             }
            });
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='es'>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

   Type your text: <input type="textarea" width="500px" height="300px">

   <p>Keys: <span>0</span></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you copy / paste or select / delete.

Comment: @volt in his question he mentioned like he is trying it as a excercise. so I don't want to confuse him and gone with his way of coding.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let myInputValueLength = 0;
$('#myInputId').on('input', function() {
    myInputValueLength = this.value.length;
    console.log(this.value.length);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/efh9z3ux/1/

Answer (score 0):

in JavaScript, you can get the pressed keyCode using `event.keyCode`.

backspace keycode value is 8 and delete keycode is 46.

So, on every keydown event, I am checking if it matches any of 8 or 46, then I can reduce the value by 1, otherwise increase the value.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 0;
  $("input").keydown(function(event) {
   console.log(event.keyCode);
    console.log(i);
    if (event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46) {
      console.log('here');
      $("span").text(i -= 1);
    } else {
     $("span").text(i += 1); 
    }
  });
});
```

I have the same code in my codepen here: https://codepen.io/gideonbabu/pen/oNgajob

For keycode, I personally use this website https://keycode.info/ from Wesbos. You can give it a try. You just go to this website and press any key on your keyboard and the website shows the keycode of the pressed keys.

Comment: Oh my Gosh, thank you so much! Very appreciated :D Have a nice day!

Comment: Hey, @triplespicy thank you and you too have a good day. I would be happy to receive an upvote/accept my answer here. This will encourage me to write more.

Comment: I only found one little problem, and it is that if I delete every single letter typed, and keep deleting, it starts counting minus numbers. Also, because I'm a beginner I really don't understand the numbers you used. Could you explain? If it's too much don't worry, don't want to bother!

Comment: Hey, @triplespicy this is just a starting point of the code. You can consider this as a boilerplate template. There are lots of things to improve in this code. Only consider the words and numbers (do not include keys like page up-down, f1, f2... f3. home, end shift tab) when type in increase the.... The numbers that I used are a unique number that we can get in JavaScript events. For example if you enter backspace, irrespective of keyboard and OS and MacBook and windows laptop, you get the same code that is 8. I would be happy to answer your questions. Don't mind to ask if you still have any.

Comment: @GideonBabu `e.which` and `e.keyCode` are both deprecated. `e.key` or `e.code` should be used instead, which also make the code easier to understand. Just keep in mind some old browsers used some non-standard codes, so left is usually `'LeftArrow'` and right is `'RightArrow'`, but on IE and Legacy Edge they would be `'Left'` and `'Right'` instead. Also, take a look at https://keyjs.dev. I will add information about these kinds of cross-browser incompatibilities soon! 

Comment: @Danziger thanks so much for your insight. BTW, your work on keyjs.dev is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

There's is no such thing as `type="textarea"`. You probably want a [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) tag. Also, you don't need jQuery for this. Vanilla JS should be more than enough.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('.my-input');
const count = document.querySelector('.count');

input.addEventListener('input', event => {
  count.innerText = event.target.value.length
});
```

```css
.my-input {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label for="my-input">Type your text:</label>
<textarea name="my-input" class="my-input"></textarea>

<div>
  <span>Count:</span>
  <span class="count">0</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, my bad. Thank you very much. Also, I need JQuery for it is better rated.  Have a nice day!